# Which property of Persistence.xml can do Hibernate Configuration as Readonly.?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, entitymanager, persistence.xml

I am using `Hibernate` **Configuration** in my `persistence.xml`. I want two persistence units. One for persisting or editing to the db. And the second persistence unit` will only have read access to db.

> **Database-readonly** will be able to perform Only Read Operation to database.

```
<persistence-unit name="Database-readonly">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
        <properties>
        .........
        .........
       <properties>
```

> **Database-Persist** will be able to perform editing to database (persist, modify or delete)

```
<persistence-unit name="Database-Persist">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
        <validation-mode>CALLBACK</validation-mode>
        <properties>
        .........
        .........
       <properties>
```

Is there any property in Hibernate configuration that will enable me to implement this ??.

I want to implement this because at the time of reading no **transactional** lock will be enabled to the database, which means multiple reading can be enabled to the `EntityManager`.

Question :- Is there any property in Hibernate configuration that will enable me to implement this ??.

Comment: Any reason of choosing persistence.xml ? `@Transactional(readOnly=true)` can solve to read the data with Hibernate `flushMode=NEVER`.

Comment: I am using Java persistent API with hibernate configuration so, I want read only setting in hibernate configuration such that I can use individual persistence unit as per need.